# Firing a click event programmatically using Kendo UI Mobile

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, jasmine, kendo-mobile

I am using Kendo UI Mobile and I am attempting to write a UI test case.  I am using Jasmine for testing.  I have the following button in my login page for my mobile app.

```
<a data-role="button" data-rel="modalview" href="#modalview-login" id="modalview-open-button">Login</a>
```

I am trying to fire that button using my test.  I am using the following code to attempt to fire that button but nothing is happening (that I can tell).

```
$("#modalview-open-button").click();
```

What I am missing?

Comment: maybe just try to call the DOM node method: `$("#modalview-open-button").get(0).click();` which is the same than: `document.getElementById('modalview-open-button').click()`

Comment: I should be able to type that into the console window, correct?

Comment: if you talk about browser console, ya. If you talk about any other console, i don't know

Comment: Yes, browser console.  See my answer as to why click() wasn't working in browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Kendo UI Mobile is trapping and handling the click() event.  I was able mimic the click event using:

```
$("#modalview-open-button").mousedown().mouseup();  // send "click()"
expect($("#modalview-login").is(":visible")).toBeTruthy();
```

I am also finding that sometimes the expect() code following the .mousedown().mouseup() is firing before the .mouseup() has completed so I am putting my test code in the callback.

```
$("#modalview-open-button").mousedown().mouseup(function() {  // send "click()"
    expect($("#modalview-login").is(":visible")).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: I should note that this has its fair share of asynchronous issues and I have at least one case where .mousedown().mouseup() doesn't work so hot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation today and found a workaround by using the following lines of code. It's not a nice solution but maybe it helps someone who is stuck in the same situation.

```
var kendoMobileButton = $("#button-id").data("kendoMobileButton");
kendoMobileButton._events.click[0]();
```

Comment: I'd love to test this but I am not working on those projects anymore.  If this gets more votes than solution (hack), I will update the accepted answer.